# Apexchart with Angularjs 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apexcharts

I am trying to generate charts in angularjs 1 using apexchart. I want to use either ng-apexchart if possible. I have the code below:

I used code from javascript but seems to be not inline with angularjs.

```
 //app.js

angular.module('plunker', ['angularCharts']);

function MainCtrl($scope) {

var chart;

$scope.showchart=function(type){

var options = {
  chart: {
  height: 380,
  width: "100%",
  type: type
 },
   series: [
   {
     name: "Series 1",
     data: [[1, 34], [3.8, 43], [5, 31] , [10, 43], [13, 33], [15, 43], [18, 33] , [20, 52]]
   }
  ],
 tooltip: {
  x: {
    formatter: function(val) {
       return val.toFixed(1);
     }
    }
 }
 };

  chart = new ApexCharts( document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

 chart.render();

 };

 $scope.hihi=function(){
  console.log("hihi");
  var dataURL = chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
   pdf.addImage(uri, 'PNG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
   })
 };

 }



  //index.html

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="plunker">

   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


   <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.2" 
      src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.2"> 
   </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://rawgit.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/bower/dist/angular- 
  charts.min.js"></script>
     <script  src = 
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.8.3/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
         <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"> 
      </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>



      <button ng-click="showchart('bar');" > Show Chart bar</button>
    <button ng-click="showchart('line');" > Show Chart line</button>
    <button ng-click="hihi();" > Submit</button>
 <div id="chart">
     </div>

   </body>

       </html>


      //style.css

      /* Put your css in here */

        #chart {
         max-width: 650px;
        margin: 35px auto;
       }
```

I could see implementation of apex chart with angular 2 versions and other technologies such as Vue, react. But I need the way apex charts are generated in angularJS 1 version.

Comment: you can't pass a percentage to width https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/width/

Answer (score 2):

Late to answer because I just had the same requirement, but if anyone is still interested I've written a small directive that wraps an `ApexCharts` instance

```
function apex() {
    return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            options: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elem) {

            // init ApexCharts and call render
            var chart = new ApexCharts(
                    elem[0],
                    scope.options
                    );
            chart.render().then(function(resolved) {
                // Once the chart is drawn on the page, a promise is returned 
            });

            scope.$watch('data', function (newData, oldOptions) {
                // newData is set of series that Apex can process
                // you will have to validate it somewhere
                chart.updateSeries(newData, true);
            });

            scope.$watch('options', function (newOptions, oldOptions) {
                // newOptions is an updated set of options
                if (angular.isObject(newOptions)) {
                    chart.updateOptions(newOptions);
                }
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                if (angular.isObject(chart)) {
                    chart.destroy();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

A few things to notice are

1. I assign an `ApexCharts` object as soon as the directive is initialized and I give it the first element in the `template`, this way I don't need to assign an `id`
2. I immediately call the [render method](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#render) `chart.render()`

> The render() method is responsible for drawing the chart on the page. It is the primary method which has to be called after configuring the options.

3. I assign a watcher and watch for new data or options, I call `chart.updateOptions(newOptions)` to update the chart without destroying it, `chart.updateSeries(newData, true)` to update the data series and force redraw.
4. I placed the `chart.destroy()` inside the scope `$destroy` event handler to clean everything up

Comment: Can I get an example in plunker.

Comment: @SajeevZacharias Got any solution?